# Wireshark not showing Frequency/Channel

Tags: ieee-802.11, wireshark

I am using Ubuntu 18, and wireshark-gtk. I followed [this](https://80211eh.com/2016/02/22/wi-fi-channels-in-wireshark/) and [this](https://unit42.paloaltonetworks.com/unit42-customizing-wireshark-changing-column-display/) tutorials to create a column named/showing frequency/channel.
But all the packets I captured have no frequency/channel showing.I tried sample packets submitted by others from wireshark.org and the frequency/chennel shows up. What might be the problem. I am trying to find the channel a packet is captured.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473359/scapy-get-set-frequency-or-channel-of-a-packet/60609951#60609951)

I [found out](http://wifinigel.blogspot.com/2013/11/what-are-radiotap-headers.html) that RadioTab headers are not part of any Dot11 protocol but are merely added by the network interface. And the reason I got the RadioTab headers on sample packets from [Wireshark.org](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#Wifi_.2F_Wireless_LAN_captures_.2F_802.11) and not from my wireshark live capture is because some network adapters do not add RadioTap header while others do and the network adapter of my laptop does not add RadioTab headers. I checked this with a new external wifi adapter and it did add the RadioTap headers.

> If the adapter does not inject the additional information as it captures frames, then no radiotap headers will be added.